# arg() and menu_get_object() are incorrect

Tags: 7, blocks

So, I have a module with a very plain `hook_block_view` in it. The hook contains definitions for around 12 blocks.

If I `var_dump(arg())` at the top of the hook and load a page with 3 or 4 of these blocks, I see something odd;

```
array (size=2)
0 => string 'node' (length=4)
1 => string '67739' (length=5)
array (size=2)
0 => string 'node' (length=4)
1 => string '67739' (length=5)
array (size=1)
0 => string 'current-player' (length=14)
```

The same happens for `menu_get_object()`, I get node object, node object, then `null`.

The path 'current-player' is defined in another modules hook_menu and is simply a redirect to the page I'm on with these blocks.

Why, on the same page, would hook_block_view have different results for arg() and menu_get_object? I can confirm that the page path has not changed, it remains the same for the load.

Comment: Is any content loaded with AJAX?

Comment: Yes. Though, not with anything to do with that path 'current-player'.

Comment: Perhaps something in the "current-player" path is doing an AJAX callback that loads the player block or page with that block in it, or maybe the server is somehow seeing the redirect path as the current path. `arg()` uses `$_GET['q']` which can be an AJAX callback. Also, maybe worth including your full `hook_block_view` and the other module `hook_menu` code to debug.